# Safari won't update rendering of SELECT when changing OPTION selected via jQuery

Tags: jquery, select, safari

Using jQuery, I'm trying to change the selected option in a SELECT element to match another input value:

```
$('#mySelect')
    .find('option')
        .filter(function() {
            return this.text == $('#selectedRejectReason').val(); 
        }).attr('selected', true)
```

When the page renders, and this JS runs, I can see it updating the DOM just fine in Safari's web inspector:

```
<select>    
    <option value="label">Select Reason</option>
<option value="Wrong Amount" selected="true">Wrong Amount</option>
<option value="Wrong Time">Wrong Time</option>
<option value="Wrong Place">Wrong Place</option>
</select>
```

When the page loads, by default, none of the OPTIONS have a SELECTED attribute...so the first item is showing. The jQuery fires, the DOM is updated so it looks like it does above, but in Safari, it still shows 'SELECT REASON' on the page. This works just fine in Firefox.

Any ideas why? Seems like a Safari bug. Alas, it's breaking our site on an iPhone.

In doing some searching, some people seem to fix this by upgrading from jQuery 1.6 to 1.7. Alas, I don't have that luxury at the moment. But if that is the fix, anyone know what changed that fixes this?

Comment: You should use `.prop` instead of `.attr` if you're using jQuery 1.6 or higher.

Comment: @Joseph please make that an answer so I can give you credit! I have no idea why that fixes it, but it does. Looking at the DOM, the markup is the same, but with PROP it updates the visual at least.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since jQuery 1.6, you should use `.prop`:

```
$('#mySelect')
    .find('option')
    .filter(function() {
        return this.text == $('#selectedRejectReason').val(); 
    })
    .prop('selected', true);
```

Take a look at the jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: that did it! Looking at the docs it seems to be an issue of setting vs. retrieving (`prop` setting).

Comment: thank you thank you thank you! only wish I found this an hour ago... :/

Comment: I found that not only must you use .prop, you can't use the .attr version before it. I was attempting to use both to update the DOM & the markup but if the .attr version comes first, the drop down does not update in Safari, even though both lines succeed. .prop alone or .prop then .attr works.

Comment: Using prop didn't work for me alone, maybe because I'm identifying the option by its value. To get it to work, I also had to assign the value of the option to the select element itself.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that in Nov 2017, I have still had to do the same solution Alan mentions. For Safari, you need to update both the prop of the option, AND the value of the select itself.

Answer (score 0):

The following function works in current Safari, Safari Mobile, Chrome, Edge, and Firefox as of this writing.

This handles the issue where the .prop calls MUST be done before the .attr calls or the entire thing is ignored, and the redraw issue in firefox.

```
    function updateSelect(selectname, value){
        $('select[name="'+selectname+'"] option').prop('selected',false);
        $('select[name="'+selectname+'"] option').removeAttr('selected');
        $('select[name="'+selectname+'"] option[value="'+value+'"]').prop('selected',true);
        $('select[name="'+selectname+'"] option[value="'+value+'"]').attr('selected','selected');
        $('select[name="'+selectname+'"]').val(value).change();
    }
```

This has a bit of additional text so that it does not get flagged as an identical answer, as it addresses a different issue on another question as well.